Null function and Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$
We know that some measurable function $f:(0,T)\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ has the following property:
For almost all $t\in (0,T)$ (Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$) we have that:
$f(t,x)=0$ for almost all $x\in\Omega$ (Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^N$).
Is it true that $f(t,x)=0$ for almost all (Lebesgue measure on $(0,T)\times\Omega$)?

This follows directly from the definition of product measures, as well as the fact that the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure is a product measure of Lebesgue measures.

Can you detail a little? What are the sets for which you apply this?

This is an application of Tonelli's theorem. Namely, suppose $(X, \mu)$ and $(Y, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $A\subset X\times Y$ is a measurable subset with the property that for $\mu$-a.e. $x$ the section $A_x:=\{y: (x, y)\in A\}$ has $\nu$-measure $0$. Then
$$(\mu\times \nu)(A)=\int_{X \times Y} {1}_A d(\mu\times \nu)=\int_X \Big(\int_Y 1_{A_x} d\nu \Big) d\mu(x)=\int_X \nu(A_x) d\mu(x).$$
Here the integrand is $0$ almost everywhere hence the integral is $0$. That is, $(\mu\times \nu)(A)=0$. Now apply this to $A=\{(t, x): f(t,x)\neq 0\}$.

Very nice solution! Thank you very much!
